# Depploying WPF app with install shield LE

Tags: wpf, deployment, installshield-le

I am deploying my WPF app with install shield LE. After installing the setup I run the program and it works. But where do the outputs of program are saved? my program creates some text docs. I don't find them! Thanks

Comment: hi, you mean you have packed your application with install shield? And excute the setup package? don't you know the path where the package  setup?

Comment: I know but outputs doesn't show up there!

Comment: what is the outputs? A folder of your app?And your app create something in this folder? Which type of path do you use? absolute or relative ? Could you provide the path of output in your code?